# Beautifulsoup: Replace all <div> with aria-level attributes with <h> tags of the same level

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML source where `<div>` elements serve as headings. Using Beautifulsoup and the attribute `aria-level` I would like to replace all `<div>` elements with `<h>` tags of the same level. My code kind of works for my purpose but it seems inelegant and ideally, the attributes of the former `<div>` elements would be removed.

```py
import bs4

html = '''<div id="container">
    <div role="heading" aria-level="1">The main page heading</div>
    <p>This article is about showing a page structure.</p>
    <div role="heading" aria-level="2">Introduction</div>
    <p>An introductory text.</p>
    <div role="heading" aria-level="2">Chapter 1</div>
    <p>Text</p>
    <div role="heading" aria-level="3">Chapter 1.1</div>
    <p>More text in a sub section.</p>
    </div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for divheader in soup.find_all("div", {"aria-level": "1"}):
    divheader.name = "h1"
for divheader in soup.find_all("div", {"aria-level": "2"}):
    divheader.name = "h2"
for divheader in soup.find_all("div", {"aria-level": "3"}):
    divheader.name = "h3"

print(soup)
```

Output:

```html
<div id="container">
<h1 aria-level="1" role="heading">The main page heading</h1>
<p>This article is about showing a page structure.</p>
<h2 aria-level="2" role="heading">Introduction</h2>
<p>An introductory text.</p>
<h2 aria-level="2" role="heading">Chapter 1</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3 aria-level="3" role="heading">Chapter 1.1</h3>
<p>More text in a sub section.</p>
</div>
```

What it should look like:

```html
<div id="container">
<h1>The main page heading</h1>
<p>This article is about showing a page structure.</p>
<h2>Introduction</h2>
<p>An introductory text.</p>
<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>Chapter 1.1</h3>
<p>More text in a sub section.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `divheader.attrs = {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `del.attrs` to delete all attributes from tag:

```py
for div in soup.select("div[aria-level]"):
    div.name = f'h{div["aria-level"]}'
    del div.attrs

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<div id="container">
<h1>The main page heading</h1>
<p>This article is about showing a page structure.</p>
<h2>Introduction</h2>
<p>An introductory text.</p>
<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>Chapter 1.1</h3>
<p>More text in a sub section.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is much more elegant; thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Note: Since HTML only defines six levels of headings, all <h> tags after aria-level="6" are not valid.

Comment: @quadratecode You can then add a if-check, if `aria-level` is greater than 6, then cap it to 6 then.